# Is it possible to display all of the Service titles in the context menu?

Tags: macos, services, shortcut-menu, contextual-menu

When one has more than three Services in a context menu, what occurs is that they are automatically kept within a "Services" sub-menu. The user then must hover over this sub-menu before they may click on the desired Service title.

Is it possible to show all 4 Service titles in the context menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show all Services on the Context Menu in Finder, do the following.

In Terminal, use the following commands:

```
defaults write .GlobalPreferences NSServicesMinimumItemCountForContextSubmenu -int 100001
killall -HUP Finder
```

Now all applicable Services in Finder's Context Menu should appear without being in a Services Sub Menu.

To revert to default behavior, use the following commands in Terminal:

```
defaults delete .GlobalPreferences NSServicesMinimumItemCountForContextSubmenu
killall -HUP Finder
```

Note: I've only tested this in OS X 10.8.5 and OS X 10.11.6 and it worked in both, so I'd assume it should work in the OS X versions in between. I've also tested this it in macOS 10.12.2 and it works, so I'd assume other versions of macOS 10.12.x it should work.

Update Note: This should also have an affect on other Context Menus in Applications other then Finder. However, applications that are running at the time this change is made must be restarted for this to take effect. After this change has been made, applications opened afterwards will be affected immediately.  You can also just logout/login for the change to take effect globally, all at once.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if this is possible in other apps as well (e.g., Chrome), or only Finder?

Comment: @rubik's sphere, See my Update Note: at the end of my answer. That said, yes it does work with the Context Menu in Google Chrome, I have tested it and it works there too.

Comment: Amazing! It works perfectly! Thank you, user3439894!!!